# how to drop a pandas multi level dataframe column when all sub columns are completely blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, drop

**dataframe:**

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Name        |    email          |  Phone no    |   Gender       |
|----------------|-------------------|--------------|----------------|
|legacy | target |legacy    | target |legacy|target |legacy | target |
|-------|--------|----------|--------|------|-------|-------|--------|
|Name1  |Name1   |n1@abc.com|        |      |       |       |        |
|Name2  |Name2   |          |        |      |   12  |       |        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Expected output:**

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|    Name        |    email          |  Phone no    |
|----------------|-------------------|--------------|
|legacy | target |legacy    | target |legacy|target |
|-------|--------|----------|--------|------|-------|
|Name1  |Name1   |n1@abc.com|        |      |       |
|Name2  |Name2   |          |        |      |   12  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

I am using the below code, but it is removing "email target" and "phone no legacy" column as well.

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However I want to drop only the "Gender" column as this is the only column where both legacy and target fields are completely blank.

Could anyone please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (I'm supposing empty cells are NaN):

```
m=df.isna().all().unstack(level=1)
cols=m[m.all(1)].index.tolist()
```

Finally use `get_level_values()`:

```
df=df.loc[:, ~df.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(cols)]
```

output of `df`:

```
         Name             Email             Phone no
    Legecy  Target  Legecy      Target  Legecy  Target
0   Name1   Name1   n1@abc.com  NaN     NaN     NaN
1   Name1   Name2   NaN         NaN     NaN     12
```

Comment: Thank you Anurag, Now it's removing column regardless of column blank values. When I tried with df=df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0)!='email']   , it's removing email as well.

Comment: @Sri Hi! you want to remove column name Gender so it is removing that one

Comment: @Sri because you are passing 'email' in `df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0)!='email'] ` so it's removing email

Comment: I want to remove the column only when both legacy and target column values of all the rows are completely blank. Thanks for your help!.

Comment: Thank you very much Anurag!  It works fine perfectly now!  It resolved my issue.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try (I'm supposing empty cells are strings `""`):

```py
m = (~df.eq("").all().groupby(level=0).all()).eq(True)
x = df.loc[:, m.index[m]]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    Name        Phone no          email       
  legacy target   legacy target  legacy target
0  Name1  Name1                  n1@abc       
1  Name2  Name2              12
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej!.  I am getting an error "IndexError: too many indices for array" on the line "x = df.loc[:, m.index[m]]"